# Understanding the jar command line

Tags: java, jar, command

So here are some of the java commands that will be executed:

> java –jar myJARfile.jar –huff –c input_file output_file
>
> java –jar myJARfile.jar –huff –d input_file output_file
>
> java –jar myJARfile.jar –lzw –c input_file output_file
>
> java –jar myJARfile.jar –lzw –d input_file output_file

I would like to know how to access each of the parameters –[huff|lzw] –[d|c] and the files on my main so I can execute the corresponding code. Are they all considered as args? Will I use args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] to access them? Or are –[huff|lzw] –[d|c] not considered as args, and if so how can I access them?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: You could just write a `main` method which prints out each element of `args` in order to find out.

Comment: @VGR Yes I did that, I had a time restraint which is why I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the **args** parameter of the **main()** method is used for. A way to test this would be:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Just for Testing args[]...
    for (String str : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
    System.exit(0);
    // --------------------------

    // --- Your method code here ---
}
```

For the different arguments you have you need to decide whether or not they need to be in a specific order. If not then you would need to code for that, here for example is one way to handle that situation:

```
// Class member variables (possible default values should be considered)...
private static String inputFile = "";              // Input File Path and File Name  [enclosed within quotation marks if whitespaces are in path]
private static String outputFile = "";             // Output File Path and File Name  [enclosed within quotation marks if whitespaces are in path]
private static String compressionType = "";        // Alternatives: HUFFMAN  (-huff) or  LZW        (-lzw).
private static String direction = "COMPRESS";      // Alternatives: COMPRESS (-c)    or  DECOMPRESS (-d).

// The main() method...
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Process Command-Line Arguments provided in any order...
    for (String argument : args) {
        switch (argument.toLowerCase()) {
            case "-huff":
                compressionType = "HUFFMAN";
                continue;
            case "-lzw":
                compressionType = "LZW";
                continue;
            case "-c":
                direction = "COMPRESS";
                continue;
            case "-d":
                direction = "DECOMPRESS";
                continue;
        }

        // Source (input) and Destination (output) files...
        if (new File(argument).exists() && new File(argument).isFile()) {
            inputFile = argument;
        }
        else {
            outputFile = argument;
        }
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Input File:       " + inputFile);
    System.out.println("output File:      " + outputFile);
    System.out.println("Compression Type: " + compressionType);
    System.out.println("Direction:        " + direction);

    // Do what you want with the variables contents ....

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused whether to count –[huff|lzw] –[d|c] as arguments. This is what I was looking for.